# Excel VBA Run-Time Error -2147221040 when Chart.CopyPicture and Locked Screen

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have been running some script that are copying Chart as Picture ( .Chart.CopyPicture ) or just copying as they are ( .ChartArea.Copy ). Those scripts are working without any problem when I am logged in but if I am on Locked Screen, it breaks with Run-Time Error -2147221040.
It is very easy to get the Error, just have a Chart, and in VBA have a script that is copying that Chart, make an autostart for the script in Excel, open the Workbook and Lock the Screen ( WIN + L ).
When you get in again, the Error is there.
I need to find a way to get it working as all my scripts are starting from Scheduler with locked screen, so I don't start those.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Now I tested something I have read on some other thread, that I didn't thought it would work as Windows Scheduler is opening the Workbook and the script is starting when the Workbook opens. The solution was to simulate a pressed key with "Application.SendKeys". So I had 2 new lines where I simulated Key Up and Key Down, and it worked, as strange as it can sound.

Application.SendKeys "{UP}"

Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"

Thanks.